# Kafka last message poll results in 0 messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka Topic (1.0.0) with a single partition. The Consumer is packed inside an EAR and when deployed to Wildfly 10, the poll of the last message always returns 0 messages. Although the topic is not empty.

```java
final TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);

final Long beginningOffset = consumer.beginningOffsets(Collections.singleton(tp)).get(tp);
final Long endOffset = consumer.endOffsets(Collections.singleton(tp)).get(tp);

consumer.assign(Collections.singleton(tp));
consumer.seek(tp, endOffset - 1);
```

When I do a poll I get 0 records. Although the logging states:

```
Consumer is now at position 377408 while Topic begin is 0 and end is 377409
```

When I change to -2 like:

```java
consumer.seek(tp, endOffset - 2);
```

I DO get one message:

```
 Consumer is now at position 377407 while Topic begin is 0 and end is 377409
```

But of course this is not the proper record, WHERE is message 377408 ?

Tried many ways to seek to end etc, but it never works.

Here is my Consumer config:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Configuration.KAFKA_SERVERS.getAsString());
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
```

Note: I tried with read_uncommitted AND read_committed, both give the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Javadoc](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-), this is because `endOffsets()` returns:

> the offset of the last successfully replicated message plus one

This is effectively the offset the next message will get.

This is why seeking to `endOffset - 1` does not return anything while seeking to `endOffset - 2` only returns the last message.

I agree this may not be the most intuitive behaviour but this is how it currently works!

Comment: no, look at the debug statements, the end is 377409 while the Consumer is at 377408, so endoffset minus one should result in message 377408. my code is also based on several examples on how to get the last message.

Comment: also, when looking at Kafka doc: consumer.position -->  Get the offset of the <i>next record</i> that will be fetched (if a record with that offset exists). So where is that record?

Comment: after some more testing, I will accept this as the answer. although the docs seem counter-intuitive.